# odoo inheriting model res.users

Tags: xml, odoo-8, access-rights

i  hope i got an answer ! 
after inheriting res.users model

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import fields, models, api

class res_users_list(models.Model):

    _inherit='res.users'


    price_list = fields.Many2many(string='Listes de prix autorisees' ,comodel_name ='product.pricelist')
```

i wanna give some users a list of allowed pricelists ! 
 here's the view :

```
 <record id="view_price_list_inherited_from" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">res.users.form.inherited</field>
  <field name="model">res.users</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.user_groups_view"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">

    <xpath expr="//separator[@string='Application']" position="after">

      <field name="price_list"
     widget="many2many_tags"
     />
      <newline/>
      </xpath>

  </field>
</record>
```

once i log in , i have this error

[image]

i really hope someone explain to me ! or a solution to get rid of this Access error "AccessError

The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: res.users, Operation: read) "

thnx all guys for the quick reply ! 
here's mi ir.model.access.csv :

```
id,name,model_id/id,group_id/id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink

access_price_list_filter,User_price_list_filter.price_list_filter,base.model_res_partner,base.group_sale_salesman,1,1,1,1

access_price_list_filter1,User_price_list_filter1.price_list_filter,base.model_res_users,base.group_sale_salesman,1,1,1,1
access_price_list_filter2,User_price_list_filter2.price_list_filter,product.model_product_pricelist,base.group_sale_salesman,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: I think you need to add security file, and give the model `res.user` the access read

Comment: Hi @Sofiane Mdj, I can help you, just i need to know the group of this user

Comment: To get the group you need to activate debug mode, by adding `?debug` after `/web`

Comment: Check your inbox message and replie us, I don't waste a time to such question

Comment: sorry for the late reply  , iwas trying to check what you guys were telling me to do ! i really appreciate ! i just updated my post adding my security file !

Comment: Active the debug mode

Comment: @Anonymousmiliana  ofc i do use debug mode ! that's just an other browser to check if my changes are working ! so wont need to switch users .

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `read access` (`write access` if you want to edit) to `res.users` for user `sos`.

This can happen when a user belongs to a group that restricts read access to the `res.users` object.

Comment: the thing is , when i install my medul i got this problem ! i take it off  , erros gone ! 
!! i notice one thing if i replace the many2many field 
with float or anything , there no problems ! so my comodel is causing that problem ! but why ?

Comment: any luck ?! cause ive been working on odoo like more than a year and half ! sometimes i got errors i cnt explain !

Comment: @Zety  !! i tried everything log in out ! down database , and create a new one ! still have that error !

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this error. Whenever you see an error like this 
**Document type: model.name, Operation: read.**

Just do these things:

The given access rights in your .csv file or the xml file were not correct or not given in the correct module.

or

There will not be any access rights given to that concerned module.

or

There will be a mistake in the record rule which mismatches with access right.

or

Any unnecessary required field is given(It sometimes do really cause this error).

I am sure that this will fix your error.

Comment: i dont think so ! cause im tryied to use it in production data base ! it has the same behaviour !

Comment: Check your .csv file for that model

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
access_price_list_filter3,User_price_list_filter3.price_list_filter,model_res_users_list,base.group_sale_salesman,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: hi , i tried ur code , i got error saying that there is no model res.users.list